# How to add WordPress back button for single page only

Tags: wordpress, button, back

I would like to add a "back" button to a single page of my WordPress site. How can I do this? I found a lot of different code options but none for WordPress specifically that will work on one page.

I can't find the individual *.PHP file for a specific WordPress page, which I think would be required to implement something like this code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="history.back();"> Back </button>
```

I tried adding this to the "Text" tab in WordPress, but there apparently is no 
`history.back` function built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add this code to your **function.php**

```
 add_action( 'back_button', 'wpse221640_back_button' );
function wpse221640_back_button() {
if ( wp_get_referer() ) {
    $back_text = __( '&laquo; Back' );
    $button    = "\n<button id='my-back-button' class='btn button my-back-button' onclick='javascript:history.back()'>$back_text</button>";
    echo ( $button );
}
}
```

add this to your **template page**

```
<?php do_action('back_button'); ?>
```

Let me know.

Comment: That added a back button to each page. I want there to be a back button on bottom of just one specific page.

Comment: Ok, you can do this: if(is_page(YOUR_PAGE_ID)) { do_action('back_button'); }

Comment: I tested it and that worked. Thank you for your help!

Comment: hello guys, is it possible to just add this when I opened or zoomed in a picture file? So that if I get forwarded to `https://***2020/09/Test.png`, I´d like to have a button to go back without using my browser button

Comment: @GabrieleFagnani why did you use wp_get_referer()? I tried this code but it's not working with it. I removed it and the button is showing up.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_shortcode( 'ekaa_back_btn' , 'ekaaBackButton');

function ekaaBackButton(){
    if ( wp_get_referer() ) {
        $button = "\n<button id='ekaa-back-button' class='btn button ekaa-back-button' onclick='javascript:history.back()'><i class='fas fa-arrow-left'></i>Back</button>";
        echo ( $button );
    }
}
```

this is work for me using WordPress Shortcode